# SQL Server Unable to convert a string to a date in a where clause (Code 241)

Tags: sql-server, string, date, substring

I have a query which cut a substring out of a char field and returns it a a date. 
And it works:

```
select 
    ujp_jobid, ujp_lfdnr,
    isnull(convert(date, substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10), 104), convert(date, getDate())) para_date,
    datediff(day, isnull(convert(date, substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10), 104), convert(date,getDate())), convert(date,getDate())) datedif
from 
    uno_jobpara 
where 
    ujp_jobid between 0 and 30000 
    and ujp_paraname = 'P_PGENDE'
```

The result is:

```
1   6   2017-11-28  8
2   372 2017-05-06  214
3   84  2017-05-01  219
```

...

I first tried the to use the datedif part as where clause:

```
...
and ujp_paraname = 'P_PGENDE' 
    and datediff(day, isnull(convert(date, substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10), 104), convert(date,getDate()) ), convert(date,getDate())) > 0
```

Suddenly the server raised an Error:

> [Code: 241, SQL State: S0001]  Fehler beim Konvertieren einer Zeichenfolge in ein Datum und/oder eine Uhrzeit.
>   (rough translation: Error converting a string to a date and/or a time)

Not quite sure why this is, but I guessed, that there the server tries to check the where conditional first and thinks that it might run into an an error.

However I tried to put in all in another select:

```
select 
    ujp_jobid, ujp_lfdnr, para_date, datedif
from 
    (select 
         ujp_jobid, ujp_lfdnr,
         isnull(convert(date, substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10), 104), convert(date,getDate()) ) para_date,
         datediff(day, isnull(convert(date, substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10), 104), convert(date, getDate()) ), convert(date, getDate())) datedif
     from 
         uno_jobpara 
     where 
         ujp_jobid between 0 and 30000 
         and ujp_paraname = 'P_PGENDE') as tt
where 
    tt.datedif > 0;
```

The same error?! Why, and how can I tell SQL Server to run a subquery first? Do I really need a temp table?

TIA

Jo

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? `SELECT @@VERSION` <- please share the output

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB4019089) - 13.0.4206.0 (X64) 
 Jul  6 2017 07:55:03 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if all parsed strings can be converted to DATE.
Since you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use `TRY_CONVERT` to test if you can convert them or not.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dd.mm.yyyy; -- This format is equivalent to format 104

SELECT 
    ujp_jobid, ujp_lfdnr,
  , substring(ujp_parawert, charindex(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1, 10)
WHERE
  TRY_CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(ujp_parawert, CHARINDEX(' ', ujp_parawert) + 1,10)) IS NULL
```

Check the records you get, those records cannot be converted.

If you get any, you have to decide if `NULL`s are acceptable or not.

- If they are, use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CONVERT/CAST`
- If `NULL` are not acceptable, you'll have to modify your expression to handle all possible variations.

`DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, day)` can be useful too if you have to modify the expression.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like something to be solved with a temp table.
Firstly I'd avoid using convert(date,getdate()) because it converts the getdate() into a string and back again, hoping that the formats fit. I'd use cast(getdate() as date).
Secondly the issue should happen in your inner query, too, if you really scroll down to the end.
You could test whether the substring is valid with a like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]'
Regards, Manfred

Comment: Why would `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` convert in two steps? Do you have any sources to support this statement?

Comment: I changed the cast - same error then I added 
and ujp_parawert like '%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
to the inner query - same error :-(